# Supremum of sets containing inequalities.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $r \in \mathbb{R}$ be fixed. Prove that:

a) $\sup\{q \in \mathbb{Q}: q \leq r\} = r$.

b) $\inf\{q \in \mathbb{Q}: q \leq r\} = r$.

It looks so strange for me that the supremum equals the infimum, Could anyone help me or at least say that the problem contains a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have for (b): $\inf \{q \in \mathbb{Q}: q \geq r \} = r$ as $\inf \{q \in \mathbb{Q}: q \leq r \} = -\infty$

You might even say that the latter expression is undefined, regardless there is certainly no real $r = -\infty$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

The statement is saying that if $r$ is a real number, you can find rational numbers as close to $r$ as you want, either a little bit greater than $r$ or a little bit less. This is easy to see if you consider the decimal expansion of $r$. For example,
$$\sqrt{2} = 1.41421\ldots$$
Consider the rational numbers
$$1.5,1.42,1.415,1.4143,1.41422,\ldots > \sqrt{2}$$
and
$$1.3,1.40,1.413,1.4141,1.41420,\ldots < \sqrt{2}.$$

Comment: This answer doesn't pick up that the question has a mistake in it.

Comment: @Ethan Alwaise   is the question true or false?